# Running EXE with parameters

Tags: c#, executable

I need help in trying to execute an executable from my C# application.
Suppose the path is `cPath`, the EXE is `HHTCtrlp.exe` and the parameter that has to be passed is `cParams`.

**How would I go about this?**

The reason why the path is a variable is that there are 3 different EXE files to run and the path will change depending on which one will run, same with the parameter string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To start the process with parameters, you can use following code:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(cPath,"HHTCtrlp.exe");
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, cParams);
```

To kill/exit the program again, you can use following code:

```
proc.CloseMainWindow(); 
proc.Close();
```

Comment: @stephen - wow it worked.  Now is there a way to kill or exit that program (the HHTCtrlp.exe) as if the exit button was clicked on it?

Comment: `Process proc = Process.Start(filename, cParams); /*...*/ proc.CloseMainWindow(); proc.Close();`

Comment: Where is cParams definition?

Comment: @Dari in the question: "and the parameter that has to be passed is cParams." ;-)

Answer (score 21):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PATH to exe", "Command Line Arguments");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat(cPath, "\\", "HHTCtrlp.exe"));
startInfo.Arguments =cParams;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: this is a code only answer, try add some explanation to your answer