# how to load local drive pdf file in adobe reader in windows form using c#?

Tags: c#

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace Ebookss
{
    public partial class Ebook : Form
    {
        string path = "D:\\samples";
        public Ebook()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listdirectory(treeView1, path);
        }

        private void listdirectory(TreeView treeview, string path)
        {
            treeview.Nodes.Clear();
            var treeviewinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            treeview.Nodes.Add(createDN(treeviewinfo));
        }

        private static TreeNode createDN(DirectoryInfo directoryinfo)
        {
            var directorynode = new TreeNode(directoryinfo.Name);
            foreach (var directory in directoryinfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                directorynode.Nodes.Add(createDN(directory));
            }
            foreach (var file in directoryinfo.GetFiles())
            {
                directorynode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));

            }
            return directorynode;
        }

        private void homeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string treenodename = treeView1.SelectedNode.ToString().Replace("TreeNode:", string.Empty);
            MessageBox.Show(path + "\\" + treenodename);
            this.adobe.LoadFile(path + "\\" + treenodename);
        }

        public object fileUri { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Process.Start()` to start executable files in C#. The .pdf-file is acutally just a parameter you give to the reader. Try this:

```
string cPath = @"C:Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\"; // Path to adobe reader
        string cParams = @"C:\temp\d.pdf";  // File you want to Open

        string filename = Path.Combine(cPath, "AcroRd32.exe");
        Process proc = Process.Start(filename, cParams);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008647/running-exe-with-parameters)'s a similar question.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: sir, i need to disable right click and hide toolbar from it for security reason in windows form?

Comment: @Bipzz Thapa You need to disable that in Adobe Reader? I'm not sure if you can do that., just like this. Can you even  do this when using Adobe Reader without a program? Maybe check the parameters that you can give to Adobe Reader..

Comment: sir, actually i want to show up doc. and pdf. type file in windows form and want to provide security to these through UI too. Can you give me any suggestion or valuable links?

Comment: How about you use a WebBrowser-Control and navigate to your file? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504442/viewing-pdf-in-windows-forms-using-c-sharp)'s a similar question that you might want to check out.